# Is there a better way to map over map values with Java streams?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Essentially, a better way to write:

```
Map<String, String> originalMap = getMapOfValues();
Map<String, String> newMap = originalMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry ->
        Maps.immutableEntry(entry.getKey(), mapValue(entry.getValue()))
    ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue);
```

(`Maps.immutableEntry` is a method from Guava)

Comment: What's wrong with this one?  What's your metric for "better"?

Comment: What's the problem with how you're currently doing it... or how does it seem suboptimal?

Comment: Simpler, as it seems there should be an easier way to do this, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907929/152873

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need to map your entries to `Maps.immutableEntry()`? You can skip that step:

```
Map<String, String> originalMap = getMapOfValues();
Map<String, String> newMap = 
    originalMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         entry -> mapValue(entry.getValue())));
```

Comment: If `Maps.immutableEntry` is the critical call for an immutable map, then this version may yield a mutable one...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele The OP's original code will result in exactly the same `Map` as mine. The immutability of the entries produces by `Maps.immutableEntry()` won't survive the `collect(Collectors.toMap())` step.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele this `immutableEntry` is completely redundant, OP is doing `.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)`

Answer (score 3):

Without using Streams, you could do the following:

```
Map<String, String> originalMap = getMapOfValues();
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>(originalMap);
newMap.replaceAll((key, value) -> mapValue(value));
```